Jupyter Notebook in vscode not rendering output and markdown cells
I am trying to run a couple of cells. Code runs fine. However, the markdown cells and the output from the code cells all don't render.
I get the following error for markdown cells: 
Error loading renderer 'vscode.builtin-renderer'

Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/notebook-renderers/renderer-out/index.js

And the following for running code cells (even when there are no errors in the code):
Error loading renderer 'vscode.builtin-renderer'

Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/notebook-renderers/renderer-out/index.js

I have tried looking up the solution,

downgrading the renderer extension,
restarting/reloading vscode,
reinstalling all jupyter extensions,
changing the kernel to (conda, base, non-venv)

